# Porque al cambiar de componente se multiplica los objetos de *ngForm?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Hola como están? estoy creando un proyecto de prueba para aprender a manejar angular 6 ya que vengo de angularjs y estoy teniendo un problema con el *ngFof o con la variable que recorre el ngFor, no estoy seguro pero cuando paso de un componente a otro y luego vuelvo al componente anterior se duplican los items del ngFor.
El flujo es el siguiente:
- La pagina Home hace un get y con el ngFor lista los datos de mi bd.
- Luego al entrar en un dato individual le paso la id de ese dato 

para obtener informacion de ese dato especifico pasando al componente proyecto.
- Al volver al componente anterior los datos del ngFor se duplican.

paso gif [aqui](https://gph.is/2AwmbaF)
,este es el código que tengo en el home.component.ts, la verdad que no me estoy dando cuenta que podría ser

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ProjectService } from '../../../service/project.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  closeResult: string;
  projects = [];
  project = {};
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private projectService: ProjectService){ 
    this.projects = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.projects = this.projectService.get();
  }
  openLg(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'lg' });
  }
  modalProject(): Observable<any> {
    let cb = Function;
  this.projectService.add(this.project, callback=>{
    this.projects.push(callback);
  });
  this.project = {};
  
  return;
  }

}
```

Gracias saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido. Hubiera sido muy positivo para la resolución de tu problema que compartas el código del servicio que estas utilizando para hacer la petición a la BD.

Recuerda que los servicios de Angular estas destinados a compartir información entre componentes, lo que significa que si tienes algún arreglo declarado en tu servicio al que le haces push cada vez que entras a tu componente **home** esta información se mantendrá en cache aunque se lance el método **OnDestroy** de **home**. Esta podría ser la razón por la que cada que vez que entras al componente **home** los datos se duplican. Si esto no soluciona tu problema, comparte el código del servicio que utilizas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Exactamente el problema era ese, muchas gracias! saludos